# How to define a Command as a StaticResource WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind a to a command defined in the `DataContext` of the `xaml` in a `DataGridColumn`, however I cannot use `RelativeSource` as columns are not part of the hierarchy, so my current solution is so define the command in the `ResourceDictionary` and reference it.

However my problem is I can't seem to find how to define an `ICommand` in the `ResourceDictionary`, how can I do this? Or any other ways to access my command in `DataContext` from a `DataGridColumn` ?

```
xmlns:input="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Input;assembly=System"

...

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <input:ICommand x:Key="propertyChangedEvent">
             "{Binding PropertyChangedEvent}"
        </input:ICommand>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Notes" MinWidth="350" Width="*" IsReadOnly="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="1">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Notes, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" BorderThickness="0" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers >
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{StaticResource propertyChangedEvent}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Why are the columns not part of the logical tree? Can you please provide the XAML markup illustrating this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Element Binding by providing element name whose has the `DatacContext`.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=DataContext.CommandPropertyName}" />
```